# Access localhost site from web server

Tags: web-services, iis, windows-server-2008

I have a site running via Visual Studio (i.e. at `http://localhost:1234`)

I need to access this site from test web server(windows/IIS). 
I can ping from the web server to my machine name.

Just wondering what I need to do to test this? to browse the site from the web server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I usually just do a quick Publish and set up a web site application in IIS to point to the published location.  I am interested to know if there is another way though.